# Ubuntu 14.04 draining laptop battery quicker than in 12.04 (1 hour versus 4+ hours)

Tags: 14.04, lenovo

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo T420 laptop (Corei7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 + Sandybridge Mobile). The battery is now over 2 years old, but under Ubuntu 12.04 it still lasted between 4 and 5 hours. Now with Ubuntu 14.04 it lasts little over one hour.

What can I do about this issue? Install drivers? Optimise the power management somehow?

**Update I**: Regarding the graphics card:

```
$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

**Update II**: Below is a sample output from PowerTop. I do not see anything strange, although I never used this programme before. Any insight is welcome.

> ```
>            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
>         2419 rpm                   Device         Laptop fan
>          8.1 ms/s     216.8        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
>         42.5 ms/s     111.7        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
>        100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D1: Conexant
>        100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: Conexant
>          6.5 ms/s      73.0        Process        /opt/ibm/lotus/notes/framework/../notes /authenticate
>          3.8 ms/s      76.7        Interrupt      PS/2 Touchpad / Keyboard / Mouse
>          1.0 ms/s      64.1        kWork          od_dbs_timer
>         15.8 ms/s      27.9        Process        compiz
>          7.7 ms/s      32.0        Process        gnome-terminal
>        214.0 µs/s      26.4        kWork          disk_events_workfn
>         24.5 ms/s      26.7        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /
>         17.9 ms/s      28.3        Process        /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
>          5.3 ms/s      31.4        Process        /usr/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /usr/share/eclipse.kepler//plugins/org.
>          1.2 ms/s      32.7        Process        /home/desousa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby script/rails s
>          1.5 ms/s      18.7        Timer          tick_sched_timer
>        372.4 µs/s      16.3        Process        [rcu_sched]
>          3.4 ms/s      12.8        Process        transmission-gtk /home/desousa/Desktop/foo.torrent
>          1.2 ms/s      11.0        Interrupt      [42]
>        464.6 µs/s       7.7        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /opt/google/talkplugin/libnpgoogletalk.so -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib
>          1.8 ms/s      10.2        Process        /opt/ibm/lotus/notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.rcp.base_6.2.3.20110915-1350/linux/x86/notes2 --launcher.suppressErr
>        492.4 µs/s       9.8        Process        [irq/44-iwlwifi]
>          1.2 ms/s       8.4        Interrupt      [0] HI_SOFTIRQ
>        100.4 µs/s       7.6        Timer          ehci_hrtimer_func
>        498.1 µs/s       7.0        Process        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.log
>          0.9 ms/s       6.1        Process        diodon
>        130.8 µs/s       6.4        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
>         38.7 µs/s       6.4        kWork          gen6_force_wake_work
>         76.9 µs/s       6.1        kWork          intel_unpin_work_fn
>        342.9 µs/s       5.6        Process        /usr/sbin/mysqld
>          0.7 ms/s       5.4        Interrupt      [3] net_rx(softirq)
>         90.6 µs/s       5.5        Interrupt      [44] iwlwifi
>          3.1 ms/s       2.9        Process        gedit
>        186.7 µs/s       4.1        Process        syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
>        179.0 µs/s       4.2        Process        /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
>        238.6 µs/s       4.1        Process        /opt/ibm/lotus/notes/taskldr /opt/ibm/lotus/notes/taskldr
> ```

**Update III**: I did another test, running the laptop until the battery was completely drained. There are two important differences in battery management from 12.04:

- Whereas with 12.04 the screen would be dimmed after 30 seconds of inaction, with 14.04 the screen is always left with the same brightness. There are even moments when the fan speeds up when I am not typing, this never happened with 12.04.
- Although I have set the laptop to suspend after 10 minutes inactive on battery, it never suspends. Once the 10 minutes are past Ubuntu simply shows the log on screen; it does not dim the screen either.

**Update IV**: I run the updates yesterday and the battery is being discharged even faster, now it is gone in less that an hour. Below is the output of `powertop` minutes after unplugging.

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 32.8 W
The estimated remaining time is 0 hours, 56 minutes

Summary: 722.8 wakeups/second,  149.5 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 23.3% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  5.55 W     63.2%                      Device         Display backlight
 90.2 mW    162.0 ms/s     220.6        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 70.7 mW     31.0 µs/s      26.3        Process        postgres: wal writer process
 21.0 mW    306.3 µs/s      30.0        Process        [irq/44-iwlwifi]
 19.6 mW      8.6 ms/s      63.0        Process        compiz
 7.63 mW      1.7 ms/s      24.5        Process        /opt/ibm/lotus/notes/notes /authenticate
 6.43 mW      2.2 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlan0 (iwlwifi)
 1.35 mW    188.5 µs/s       2.3        Process        diodon
 997 µW      77.2 µs/s       2.6        Process        syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
 798 µW       4.2 ms/s      19.3        Process        /usr/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /usr/share/eclipse.kepler//plugins/org.
 499 µW     394.4 µs/s       1.1        Process        gnome-terminal
 299 µW       2.3 ms/s       7.0        Process        mono /usr/lib/tomboy/Tomboy.exe --search
    0 mW      3.9 µs/s      0.15        Process        sametime_idlemon 20 10
    0 mW     13.7 ms/s       5.1        Process        /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
    0 mW     12.6 ms/s      17.7        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /
    0 mW      6.1 ms/s     163.9        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
    0 mW      2.7 ms/s      25.6        Interrupt      [42] i915
    0 mW      2.5 ms/s      14.4        Timer          tick_sched_timer
    0 mW      2.0 ms/s      19.2        Process        rhythmbox
    0 mW      1.9 ms/s       7.5        Process        /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
    0 mW      1.3 ms/s      63.2        kWork          od_dbs_timer
    0 mW      1.3 ms/s      0.00        Timer          delayed_work_timer_fn
    0 mW      0.9 ms/s      0.05        kWork          acpi_os_execute_deferred
    0 mW      0.8 ms/s      0.00        Interrupt      [1] timer(softirq)
    0 mW      0.7 ms/s      53.4        kWork          disk_events_workfn
    0 mW    629.9 µs/s       0.8        Process        chromium-browser --enable-pinch
    0 mW    561.9 µs/s      19.5        Process        /home/desousa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby script/rails s
    0 mW    508.1 µs/s      0.10        Process        powertop
    0 mW    496.9 µs/s       5.3        Process        /opt/ibm/lotus/notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.rcp.base_6.2.3.20110915-1350/linux/x86/notes2 --launcher.suppressErr
    0 mW    468.2 µs/s       0.8        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
    0 mW    281.6 µs/s       4.1        Interrupt      [4] block(softirq)
    0 mW    276.5 µs/s       3.1        kWork          iwl_bg_run_time_calib_work
    0 mW    260.5 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      PS/2 Touchpad / Keyboard / Mouse
    0 mW    200.0 µs/s      15.6        kWork          intel_unpin_work_fn
    0 mW    173.5 µs/s       4.6        Process        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.log
    0 mW    160.9 µs/s      0.00        Process        [kworker/u16:0]
    0 mW    160.3 µs/s      0.25        Process        pool
    0 mW    159.0 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [9] RCU(softirq)
    0 mW    147.4 µs/s       4.0        Process        /usr/sbin/mysqld
    0 mW    144.9 µs/s       0.4        Interrupt      [9] acpi
    0 mW    131.4 µs/s      10.3        Interrupt      [44] iwlwifi
    0 mW    129.5 µs/s       2.0        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /opt/google/talkplugin/libnpgoogletalk.so -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib
    0 mW    128.7 µs/s       4.7        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
    0 mW    118.9 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [40] SATA controller
```

**Update V**: I used the information provided by `powertop` to make a few calculations:

- At the discharge rate reported, the battery right now has about 32 Wh of capacity;
- The battery is advertised with a capacity [close to 100 Wh](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/lenovo-thinkpad-t420-review-the-best-business-laptop/4/) when new, lasting up to 15 hours;
- With Ubuntu 12.04 the battery was lasting about 4.5 hours, about 1/3 of 15 hours, squaring exactly with a loss of 2/3 of capacity;
- Thus, with Ubuntu 12.04 the average discharge rate must have been around 7 W.

An increase of power consumption from 7 W to 32 W is nothing short of catastrophic. Whatever is causing this must be far more serious than just some guzzler application or a misconfigured package.

**Update VI**: I am writing this from a live 14.04 session loaded from a USB key. Power consumption seems to be somewhat lower than with the HDD system (80% - 90%), which can be explained by a reduced number of services and applications running. Still, battery lifetime is far lower than what it was with Ubuntu 12.04.

**Update VII**: the abnormally high discharge rates are back, apparently after an upgrade to `linux-headers-generic` around the 15th of July. This is now reported as [a bug at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1347539).

Any hints on how to bring back battery lifetime would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to disable your video card from Bios, if you have that option, when you start your laptop.

Comment: Do you have discrete video card installed? Please add output of `lspci | grep -i --color 'vga'`

Comment: Try to install powertop and see which application drains most of your battery: sudo apt-get install powertop.

Comment: I would advice a re-install to make sure the upgrade did not mess something up.

Comment: A re-install is not an option at this moment. But this gives me the idea of trying Ubuntu 14.04 from a live medium.

Comment: Try updating to the latest mainline kernel.

Answer (score 3):

You may try linrunner's [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) app. 
The package can be found at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/tlp), or simply add the PPA into your `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install tlp
```

Comment: Hi Ish, I already had TLP installed, but was missing the ThinkPad specific packages (`acpi-call-tools` and `tp-smapi-dkms`). I installed these and gave it a try, the battery when from 100% down to 20% in just 70 minutes.

Comment: Doesn't sound encouraging. [Jupiter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter) is a deprecated app but I know folks who successfully used it previously to configure the power options. You could give it a try if you haven't already.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa did you try this guide http://askubuntu.com/a/285681/265974 ?

Comment: Hi Xubu-Tur, thanks for stopping by. I already have all the packages indicated in that answer for ThinkPads installed. As for the monitoring applications, they do not seem to do more than `powertop`. Considering the dramatic decline in battery lifetime (now less than 1/4 of what it was with 12.04) I am starting to doubt this is related to a particular package.

Answer (score 2):

Type:- `sensors` it will show your cup temperature.
To save battery :

1- Reduce brightness

2- Install TLP. (remove PowerTop and Laptop-mode-tools first)

```
sudo apt-get purge powertop laptop-mode-tools
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linrunner/tlp && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y tlp tlp-rdw
```

3- Turn Off Bluetooth when not in use.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran the updates and rebooted the laptop again. Lo and behold, power consumption is now down to 11 W, the screen is dimming automatically and the session locked after 5 minutes inactive.

I am trying to find which package update may have fixed power management, but there is nothing obvious in the `apt` history:

```
Start-Date: 2014-05-28  14:09:15
Commandline: apt-get install rabbitvcs-cli rabbitvcs-core rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-nautilus3
Upgrade: rabbitvcs-cli:amd64 (0.16-1~precise, 0.16-1~trusty), rabbitvcs-gedit:amd64 (0.16-1~precise, 0.16-1~trusty), rabbitvcs-nautilus3:amd64 (0.16-1~precise, 0.16-1~trusty), rabbitvcs-core:amd64 (0.16-1~precise, 0.16-1~trusty)
End-Date: 2014-05-28  14:10:09

Start-Date: 2014-05-30  10:06:25
Commandline: apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
Install: libcpufreq0:amd64 (008-1, automatic), indicator-cpufreq:amd64 (0.2.2-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2014-05-30  10:07:06

Start-Date: 2014-05-30  14:04:43
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: im-config:amd64 (0.24-1ubuntu4, 0.24-1ubuntu4.1), nemo-data:amd64 (2.2.2-0~webupd8~trusty0, 2.2.2-0~webupd8~trusty1), nemo:amd64 (2.2.2-0~webupd8~trusty0, 2.2.2-0~webupd8~trusty1), libnemo-extension1:amd64 (2.2.2-0~webupd8~trusty0, 2.2.2-0~webupd8~trusty1)
End-Date: 2014-05-30  14:06:02

Start-Date: 2014-05-30  14:38:11
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.104'
Install: syslinux-themes-debian-wheezy:amd64 (12-3, automatic), unetbootin-translations:amd64 (585-2ubuntu1, automatic), syslinux-themes-debian:amd64 (12-3, automatic), extlinux:amd64 (4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1, automatic), unetbootin:amd64 (585-2ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2014-05-30  14:38:47
```

In any case, the fix to this issue seems simply to update the system:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

I will keep this answer up to date if I find exactly which package(s) where concerned.

**Update**: there was another package upgrade last week that sent the battery discharge rate off the charts again. I am still not certain which package is behind this, but it seems to be `linux-headers-generic`.

Answer (score 1):

I run my laptop on solar power all the day and have limited power.
Reducing CPU clock speed helps the most in my experience.

You can install CPUfreq tool, and set a Powersave option or manually set the lowest clock speed.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Also switching off Wifi from device physical on/off switch will improve battery timing significantly

Comment: Hi Abdullah, I just tried CPUfreq. I am able to reduce power consumption by some 10% to 15% using its tweaks, but the laptop becomes somewhat unusable. Access to the HUD and Lens is especially slow and programmes easily hang up (greyed out). Even accepting these constraints, power consumption is far from what it was with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Luis de Sousa , to share with you my experience. I've a Sony VAIO Core 2 Due laptop, I've been on 10.04, 10.10, 12.04 and now 14.04. There is no difference in Power Consumption, though I feel a little (10%-15%) performance hit now that I'm on 14.04. There is nearly 35% - 40% reduced power consumption. Nearly another 10% when I switch Wifi down.