# Ubuntu 14.04 draining battery very quickly

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

I know there are several other questions very similar to this, but I feel that questions like this are specific to the system you are running and so there is not really a "one size fits all" type of fix.

Im still very new to Ubuntu and so am still figuring things out. When I first installed Ubuntu it had some freezing issues but after asking a question and downloading the NVIDIA driver I haven't had a problem since with freezing.

Now however my battery seems to been draining at a very quick pace (a percent about every minute and a half).  I don't remember having this problem when I first installed ubuntu, it seemed to run for a good while before draining the battery.

My assumption (with some research added on) is that after installing the NVIDIA driver it is using my high powered video card constantly, instead of only when needed (I'm using a dell precsion laptop that has integrated video and a dedicated one).  This would explain the very quick loss of battery.

However I'm not quite sure what to do about it.  I heard of a program called bumblebee that might solve my problems but I'm not save enough to know whether it will or not at this point.  Any input or thoughts would be appreciated, I would really like to get this solved!

"Edit": I have  tried bumblebee and that totally screwed up the graphics so I did a fresh install of ubuntu and am back to where I started now. I will try tlp as a guy below suggest and see what happens.

I would also like to mention that the computer battery seemed to be about average until I re-installed the nvidia driver, which seemingly begain to reduce my battery life again. I believe this gives even more evidence towards my first hypothesis about the nvidia driver.

Comment: Did you try [TLP](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681) or another Nvidia driver? Did you read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/461620/ubuntu-14-04-draining-laptop-battery/461623#comment620857_461623 ?

Comment: I dowloaded the nividia "current driver" from the ubuntu software center.  I did read that but in this case I dont think its a case of saving power from everything in use as much as it is getting the onboard video card working for most of the time and the dedicated one when i need it...I will try and uninstall the nividia driver and see if that helps any, if not I will try the suggestions in the article

Comment: It appears that hitting the remove button in the ubuntu software center does not uninstall/disable it, is there any way to do this? This is what I got "NVidia binary X.Org driver ('current' driver)" from linux's version of the app store

Comment: Its better to try first TLP.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but now I've repaired

Just do not use the battery only Make actuation device charger directly

The only problem is the electricity If goes out will stop the machine

Comment: I dont really feel this is a solution to the problem, more of a patch and would rather figure out a good way to get ubuntu to stop using so much power

Comment: @zyphon7: This is usually called [workaround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround).

Comment: That still does not fix my problem, and I want it fixed, I shouldnt have to have an outlet near me everytime I want to use linux